# Metal/good conductor frame in a changing magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, potential, voltage, electromagnetic-induction

Imagine that we put a metal/good conductor frame into a changing magnetic field. Due to the fact that this is an electromagnetic induction phenomenon, an induced EMF can be measured between the two terminals of the conducting frame (see the image below).

[image]

To the best of my knowledge, a metal/good conductor is equipotential, and the electric field inside it is always zero. So how is this possible, that there will be a potential difference between terminal A and B?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the magnetic field into the screen is increasing, there will be a non-conservative electric field urging positive charge around the conductor from A towards B.

Positive charge will then pile up on B, leaving negative on A. These charges will set up a conservative (Coulombic) electric field in the conductor acting from B towards A.

In a very short time (if the magnetic field continues to increase steadily) the resultant electric field in the conductor will be zero, yet there will be a potential difference between A and B due to the build-up of static charge.

["a metal/good conductor is equipotential, and the electric field inside it is always zero." This is not the case. An ordinary conductor carrying a current has an electric field along it. Otherwise there'd be no current.]

Comment: If I were to measure the voltage between A and B with a digital multimeter, attaching the common/ground probe to point B and moving the other probe starting from point B towards point A along the frame, then would I see that the voltage is rising continuously?

Comment: With a set-up like this, it all depends on where you place the multimeter and route your leads in relation to the conducting path: more specifically, how much flux is enclosed by the loop consisting of the pre-existing conductive path and the completion of the loop by the voltmeter and its leads. I'm afraid I can't give you a clear answer for two reasons (a) because of what I've just written (b) I'm not clever enough.

Comment: An easier set-up to deal with is a coil of many turns. In that case the total flux linkage enclosed by the circuit is hardly affected by the placing of the voltmeter, because so much of the flux linkage is due to the complete turns of the coil. In this set up the voltage measured between one end of the coil and  'tappings' at equal incremental numbers of turns along the coil will indeed rise proportionally to the number of turns (assuming a constant rate of rise of flux from another source).

Comment: I understand your coil of many turns example, thanks for that! I think what I have written before that a metal/good conductor is equipotential is only true if you place it for example into an electric field generated by a point charge. But I guess it won't hold true if you place it into a circular electric field generated by changing magnetic flux. Am I right?

Comment: One more thing related to the answer you have given. Imagine that the magnetic flux into the screen is increasing. Then based on Maxwell-Faraday equation a circular electric field will be produced, and its orientation will be counter-clockwise. Are you sure that "positive charges will then pile up on A, leaving negative on B". Isn't it quite the opposite?  I mean that positive charges will pile up on B, leaving negative on A?

Comment: (a) Your comment "I understand ...": You'll get movement *at first* when you place a conductor in the field due to static charge(s). But some free charges will move to the surface of the conductor until their fields inside the conductor cancel that of the external charges. This happens very quickly, and we then have 'electrostatic conditions'. You are right that this won't happen with a changing magnetic field – except when charge can pile up as in your original question! (b) Thank you for pointing out my mistake. Embarrassing!

Comment: No, it is absolutely not embarassing. That is how science works and how people learn. That's why I asked my question in the first place. Thank you very much for your answers, they were enlightening! :)

Answer (score 1):

the electric field is not always zero.

If the magnetic field changes steadily, a steady non-zero voltage builds up between A and B in accordance to faraday's induction law.

Comment: Imagine that the magnetic field into the screen is increasing. At which terminal of the frame will be the potential higher? At terminal A or B?

Answer (score 1):

according to Maxwell's equations, the changing magnetic field can produce non-conservative electric field which make electrons move along with the conductor.

this non-conservative electric field is called vortex electric field .

Comment: Will the electric field inside a conductor sooner or later become zero in a non-conservative electric field too?